# how can i make my pycharm identify odoo modules

Tags: python, pycharm, odoo-15

hello I am using pycharm community for odoo development, but I have a problem when I created a module I tried this:

```
from odoo import fields, models, api
```

but there is an error `"cannot find references models api fields"`

I have already added the addons path and my custom addons path to the conf file

```
addons_path=/home/abdo/odoo15/odoo/addons,/home/abdo/odoo15/odoo/custom_addons
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have an `odoo` folder/script in your project?

Comment: yes i do I am following a playlist in YouTube for odoo development (odoo mates)i have already done everything like him but still have that error

Comment: Then python tries to import these from your own script/folder, not from the `odoo` package. The easiest way is to rename your script/folder from `odoo` to something else

Comment: unfortunately same error